# Importing modules from a folder in python27

Tags: python, import, module, python-2.7, directory

This sounds ridiculous as there appears to be an unlimited number of responses to this question on this site - but I can't find a straightforward solution without temporarily changing my system path for each reload (or **init**, which doesn't work for my setup). I'm looking for a secure, non-hacky way of getting this done.

Simply put - I have a directory structure as follows:

```
**root**
>main.py
>**modules**
  >>rivescript.py
  >>js.py
>**plugins**
  >>weather.py
  >>synd.py
```

To make it simple, I would like to import every available module in the presented subdirectories (modules, plugins) natively in main.py

Pseudo:

```
#main.py
import "./modules/*.py" as modules_*
import "./plugins/*.py" as plugins_*
```

And be able to call functions as something like:

```
plugins_weather.get("3088")
modules_rivescript.RiveScript.reply("localuser", language_input)
```

Any suggestions? Speed and resource consumption are a big thing for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should put __init__.py files (which could be empty) in modules/ and plugins/ directories, to mark them as packages.

Now, you are able to import your modules in main.py:

```
import modules.js as js
import modules.rivescript as rivescript

import plugins.weather as weather
import plugins.synd as synd

weather.get("3088")  # Usage example
```